# PDE equation in 3rd dim

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find general solution.
$$ U_{xx} + U_{yy}+ U_{zz} + 2\left(U_{xy}+U_{xz}+U_{yz}  \right) = U$$

This is equivalent to

$$ \left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^2 U\left(x,y,z \right) =  U\left(x,y,z \right)$$

The characteristic surface is given by

$$ \left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) W\left(x,y,z \right) = 0$$
This is what I could

How to find solution? Thank you!

Comment: but this is not general solution, wolfram mathematica say $e^x f \left(-x + y, -x + z \right) + e^{-x} g \left(-x + y, -x + z\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We straighten the vector field

$$ x \rightarrow x, \, y \rightarrow f=y-x, \, z \rightarrow g=z-x $$

Determinant of the Jacobi matrix $det(J) = 1$

Then
$U \left(x,y,z \right) = V \left(x,f,g \right)$ and $ \left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \rightarrow \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} $

and then equation $$ V_{xx} = V$$ has solution $ V = e^x C_1 \left(f, g \right) + e^{-x} C_2 \left(f, g\right) $ and $$U\left(x,y,z \right) = e^x C_1 \left(-x + y, -x + z \right) + e^{-x} C_2 \left(-x + y, -x + z\right)$$